# How to change active tab in iframe header when on different page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an imported header via iframe on my HTML page. I want a way to make the current page active, but can't just change it to the active class in the header, because it would make it active on all pages.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to show some code and better explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish, along with your attempt

Comment: iFrameing a header on each page seems like a strange way of going about it.  You could use a backend language to "grab" the header and "place" it on the page .. Like `php`s **include**  --  <?php include('header.php'); ?>  Then you can have some logic inside `header.php` to determine which tab should be active based on the parameters you set ..

Comment: @Kinglish okay, sorry, I'll leave.